# Eclipse Generate Javadoc Wizard: what is "Javadoc Command"?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I want to generate the javadocs for an open-source code-base I'm using. But I'm being asked for a "Javadoc Command" by the Eclipse Generate JavaDoc wizard and the help doesn't explain what this means. Is it wanting the path to the javadoc binary/jar or something else?

Comment: path of javadoc.exe
e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javadoc.exe

Comment: For linux users, the `javadoc` resides in `/usr/lib/jvm/<your java version>/bin` directory.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, presumably it wants the path to the [`javadoc` command line tool](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) that comes with the JDK (in the bin directory, same as `java` and `javac`).

Eclipse should be able to find it automatically; are you perhaps running it on a JRE? That would explain the request.

Comment: That's what confused me. I downloaded the newest JDK and under "installed JREs" I have checked jdk1.6.0_20 - isn't that right?

Comment: Oh, I see. I set the JRE path as ...\jdk\jre, not ...\jdk, thinking that's what was required. Doh!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is asking for the application/executable that is capable of creating Javadoc. There is a `javadoc` executable inside the jdk's bin folder.

Comment: e.g. on windows JAVA_HOME/bin/javadoc.exe

Comment: ^^ if you installed the jdk, the jre version does not have that tool

Answer (score 8):

You may need to add a JDK (Java Development Kit) to the installed JRE's within Eclipse

Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE's

In the Name column if you do not have a JDK as your default, then you will need to add it.

Click the "Add" Button and locate the JDK on your machine.
You may find it in this location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.y
Where x and y are numbers.

If there are no JDK's installed on your machine then download and install the Java SE (Standard Edition) from the Oracle website.

Then do the steps above again.  Be sure that it is set as the default JRE to use.

Then go back to the Projects->Generate Javadoc... dialog

Now it should work.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem and solved typing this : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javadoc.exe

Comment: For me the solution was: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javadoc.exe`

Answer (score 0):

There are already useful answers to this question above, however there is one more possibility which I don't see being addressed here.

We should consider that the java is installed correctly (that's why eclipse could have been launched in the first place), and the JDK is also added correctly to the eclipse. So the issue might be for some reason (e.g. migration of eclipse to another OS) the path for javadoc is not right which you can easily check and modify in the javadoc wizard page. Here is detailed instructions:

1. Open the javadoc wizard by `Project->Generate Javadoc...`
2. In the javadoc wizard window make sure the `javadoc command` path is correct as  illustrated in below screenshot:

[image: EclipseJavadocWizard]