# Create javadoc in eclipse

Tags: android, javadoc

When trying to generate Javadocs for an Android project, I go to Project>Generate Javadoc, but the first line asks for a "Javadoc Command". What goes there?

Comment: what dou you want to gain? Generated javadoc from your classes? You want in in eclipse, or in java commandline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Generate Javadoc Wizard: what is "Javadoc Command"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091711/eclipse-generate-javadoc-wizard-what-is-javadoc-command)

Answer (score 4):

Project -> Generate Javadoc. See [here](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/generating-javadoc-in-eclipse-ide.html).

In order to do it, you have to have JDK installed and Eclipse must be aware of it.
Download [one](http://jdk6.java.net/).

Comment: i dont have a javadoc.exe file

Comment: Updated. Please, formulate your questions clearly. We are not mediums here, we can't know about your actual problems if you don't write about them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the "javadoc.exe" because when you install eclipse it installs only the java JRE, and the "bin" folder from JRE doesn't have javadoc. Go to this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u9-downloads-1859576.html
and download the JDK.
When you install JDK, look for "javadoc.exe" in the installed folder, you will find it in "bin" folder under your installed folder.
Now you can reference it in "Javadoc Command" from eclipse by clicking in the "Configure" button.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the path to the javadoc command line tool that comes with the JDK (in the bin directory, same as java and javac).
e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin